# Como passar mensagem da exceção para uma página HTML a partir de uma JSP?

Tags: java, html, exceção, jsp

Eu tenho um exercício da faculdade no qual tenho que criar uma pagina .jsp que recebe como parâmetro um "id" e roda uma query para deletar o registro dentro da classe produtos com esse id e caso de alguma exceção que eu mande o usuário para pagina erro.html passando como parâmetro o texto do erro.
O código que fiz até agora foi esse:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="web.acesso.bd.*,web.acesso.bd.dao.*"%>
<html>  
<head><title>Insert title here</title></head>  
<body>   
<% 
int myId=request.getParameter("id")
try{
    bd.execComando ("DELETE FROM Filme id="+myId+");
} 
catch(Exception e)
{
   response.sendRedirect("erro.html");
}%>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Até aqui acho que está certo, mas eu não sei passar como parâmetro a mensagem da exceção que está na variável "e".
Alguém poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

Talvez algo assim resolva:

```
<% 
   int myId=request.getParameter( "id" );

   try{
      bd.execComando ( "DELETE FROM Filme WHERE id=" + myId );
   } 
   catch( Exception e )
   {
      response.sendRedirect( "erro.html?excecao=" + URLEncoder.encode( e, "ISO-8859-1" ) );
   }
%>
```

O URLencoder vai servir para converter espaços e caracteres especiais sa mensagem em algo que possa ser transmitido justamente por URL, bastando você acertar a conversão para o que necessitar. Pus ISO-8859-1 por ser o mesmo que você usou na primeira linha do código original.

Isto é claro, supondo que intenção seja de a página de erro processar o parâmetro `excecao` para exibir para o usuário final.

Comment: Boa, não sabia desse URLEncoder,você deu olhada no resto do código,acredita que está certo?

Comment: Tinha uns probleminhas de sintaxe, acho que tão resolvidos.